# Solve the recurrence relation $T(n) = nT^2(n/2)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Solve the recurrence relation $T(n) = nT^2(n/2)$ with initial condition $T(1) = 6$.

So far I believe that I should let $n = 2k$ and then make the substitution for $ak = \log T(2k)$. From here I am stumped, any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can't solve it completely. That recurrence relation will only determine the values of $T(2^k)$. All odd numbers are free to take on any value.

Comment: Can you post your work I'm having trouble understanding what you mean?

Comment: What work is there to post? You know what $T(1)$ is. The recursion relation will tell you $T(2)$, and then $T(4)$, then $T(8)$, etc. There is no way to pick up $T(3), T(5), T(6), ...$. All you can do is move up or down the powers of 2.

Comment: Are you trying to get a rough solution of the form $T(n)=\Theta(f(n))$ for some simple function $f(n)$?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is for a computer science class and you've omitted floors/ceilings for brevity, here's a hint: set $U(n)=\lg T(n)$ (or use your favorite base). Take the log of both sides of the recurrence and express the result in terms of $U$; you get
$$U(n)=2 U(n/2)+\lg n.$$

Now apply the master theorem to determine $U(n)$, and now you know $T(n)$ since $T(n)=2^{U(n)}.$

Answer (score 0):

Use Range Transformations skill:

$$ T(n)=nT^2(n/2), T(1)=6, n=2^k $$
$$ T(2^k)=2^kT^2(2^{k-1}), T(1)=6 $$
$$ Let\ a_k=T(2^k)$$
$$ a_k=2^k(a_{k-1})^2, a_0=6 $$
$$ Let\ b_k=\log_2a_k $$
$$ b_k = 2b_{k-1} + k, b_0=\log_26 $$
$$ b_k=(3+\log_23)2^k-k-2 $$
$$ T(n)=2^{3n-2}3^n/n $$